# Why are pipe characters horizontal when using bxcjkjatype?

Tags: cjk, arxiv, japanese

I have written a paper in English that includes Japanese text. I originally wrote it using xecjk but am converting it to use PDFLatex and bxcjkjatype for Arxiv. Following the instructions [here](https://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/cjk-on-arxiv/) mostly worked, but for some reason pipe characters in a table have turned into horizontal lines. The first line, second column here should be `見|た`, but the pipe is rotated and at an odd height.

[image]

I could understand the character being rotated if I was using vertical typesetting, but I'm not doing that at any point in the document.

Is there a way I can make the pipes vertical again?

Comment: Show a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem. That makes it much easier to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not shown any code but I assume you have the equivalent of

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


a | b

\end{document}
```

[image]

The original 7-bit (OT1) encoding used for TeX fonts does not have a `|` character except in  math mode and tt for verbatim.

Use the 8bit T1 encoding for latin script sections:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}


a | b

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it for me.